# PHP flush information in controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, flush

I am trying to send data to view from controller in PHP CodeIgniter.
I am calling the PHP function through `ajax` and using `ob_flush` to send data back but the problem is that all the flush calls are concatenated in later calls.

For example: the first flush send `1` second flush call send `12` instead of `2`.

This is my controller loop.

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
    ob_start();
    $varint=$varint+1;
    echo $varint;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $content;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```

My ajax call is this:

```
document.getElementById('upld').onclick = function() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var mydata = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
    xhr.open("POST", base_url+"index.php/controller/function", true);
    xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data='') {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(myArr);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(mydata);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) says:

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser. It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering mechanism. This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those.

In your case you can replace `flush()` with [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) as I don't think you are looking to flush the system output buffers.

As a little extra this code:

```
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Can be condensed into one function call that is an alias for both of the previous commands combined:

```
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

[Documentation for `ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: David thanks for your response. I have tried `ob_flush();` and `flush()` but that doesn't help either. And when I try just `ob_flush();` that doesn't send data to front-end at all